# Can't include appendix

Tags: appendices

I'm writing my thesis and I need to add an appendix. I'm using a main file as a frame with \input for importing the single chapters.

For the appendix I'm doing this:

```
\appendix
\input{AppendixA.tex}
```

But when I try to compile the file, it doesn't show the Appendix. Any ideas of what the problem could be?

Code of the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\maketitle

\body

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\input{Conclusions.tex}


\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\bibliography{bibliography}


\appendix
\input{AppendixA.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *full* (yet minimal) code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I just added it in the question

Comment: @Barbara: What is inside `AppendixA.tex`?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Inside AppendixA.tex I have the following structure: \chapter{name} \section{name} and them a list created with itemize

Comment: Are there any error messages in the log file?

Comment: @Barbara: 'Casting' your comment about the contents of `AppendixA.tex` into a file and removing the `\body` statement (what is `\body`?), I get the appendix appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given data, I was not able, to reproduce your problem.

Maybe, there is a problem in the content of the two `\include`s before the Appendix starts?

I had problems with the command `\body` indead.

I also want to point out, that you do not need to add the `.tex` extension as argument to `\input`.

This is my MWE:

```
documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum} % <--- added to get some text

\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{ch3} % <--- contains only \lipsum[3-20]

\chapter{Conclusions}
\input{ch3} % <--- same as above

\appendix
\input{ch4} % <--- another \lipsum

\end{document}
```

I got the chapter Bar correctly in the appendix, without changing its definition, as Saravan suggested in his answer.

[image]

Maybe you'll really have to investigate in your files `Introduction.tex` and `Conclusion.tex?

Comment: I think the error was `\body`...

Comment: Maybe Christian.  I hope, I could help @barbara and she'll get her document to compile without error.

Comment: She has accepted your answer ;-) The only command `\Body` I know is from `newenviron` package, so it may be  a typo (but at the position it does not make sense!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: fine :-)  I'm glad, we both could help her.  Is there a possibility, to part the 25 credit points to give you 12,5 of them?

Comment: Well, you answered before I could, the 25 reputation belong to you, of course... I am not really short of reputation...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and Jan Thanks a lot to the both of you! You were really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Include the below coding before the `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\appendixname\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Barbara told "it doesn't show the Appendix" which means Appendix word.

Comment: I think she rather referred to the whole appendix content, not the word **Appendix** itself.